# Why can I pass a "C string" to a function expecting a std::string and it works?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a method:

```
void Foo::Bar(const std::string &str)
{
    printf("%d", str.length());
}
```

and it works seamlessly when I do

```
foo.Bar("hello");
```

I thought `"hello"` was a `const char *`, not a `std::string`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways user-defined types can be implicitly converted:

1. With a conversion constructor (e.g. "std::string::string(const char* c_string)").
2. With a conversion operator (e.g. "OldType::operator NewType() const").

Any constructor that takes a single parameter and does not use the keyword "explicit"  defines an implicit conversion (from the type of the parameter, to the type of the object being constructed). The standard string class intentionally does not use "explicit" in order to provide the convenience of this conversion.

Answer (score 8):

Because std::string has a constructor that takes a `const char *`, C++ will automatically construct a temporary string object for you.

Comment: Importantly, a _non-explicit_ constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Technically it's a `char const[6]` but yes you should be able to do this thanks to implicit conversion and one of `std::string` constructors.

Answer (score 2):

somewhat related to your question: if there is a time in C++ where you **explicit**ly don't want the compiler to change types for you like this, when a compatible constructor exists, you use the keyword "explicit" before the constructor. Then it will give you a compiler error. You can only do this with the types you create, however. Not with STL types like string.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an ?implicit? conversion from `char *` to `std::string` using the `std::string(char *)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your string literal is a `char const[6]`.

The name of it decays to `const char*` for passing to the function.

Then an implicit conversion is performed, because:

- The function accepts a ref-to-const, meaning an `rvalue` can be bound to it
- The `const char*` can be implicitly converted into an `std::string` `rvalue`.